# The specified object is not recognized as a fake object. Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, tdd, nunit, fakeiteasy

I am having an issue where a FakeItEasy call in an extremely simple test is failing with the error "The specified object is not recognized as a fake object."  The call is simple:

```
A.CallTo(myService.MyMethod(listOfStringsFilter)).MustHaveHappened();
```

The fake is similarly simple (A.Fake()), and fakes out an interfance with one method, that takes in a list and returns a list.  In debug mode, I see the instance of myService is of type {Fake IMyInterface}.  Anyway, this issue is really holding me up, thanks in advance for your help.

**Update:**

This was my own darn mistake, I needed to make the call say:

```
A.CallTo(() => myService.MyMethod(listOfStringsFilter)).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: You should post your resolution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours, I'm not cool enough to do that yet ;).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was my own darn mistake, I needed to make the call say:

```
A.CallTo(() => myService.MyMethod(listOfStringsFilter)).MustHaveHappened();
```